# Spring Cloud Config server - can't resolve from configuration repository

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-config

I am trying to build a set of related services, Discovery, Admin, Config and a plain rest service.

- [REST Service](https://github.com/mnrasul/springservice)
- [Config Service](https://github.com/mnrasul/springconfig)
- [Underlying git repo where configurations are stored](https://github.com/mnrasul/configurations)
- [Registry Service](https://github.com/mnrasul/spring-cloud)
- [Admin service](https://github.com/mnrasul/springadmin)

For the purpose of the question, I am having problem read the configuration in `SpringService`, the rest service.

### Problem 1:

`Config-Service` comes up cleanly. However, it only recognizes the values from `application.yml`. It doesn't see the `message.yml` in the `configurations` repo.

### Problem 2:

`Spring-service`, poorly named, is the rest endpoint. It expects to read a configuration from `config-service`, however, it fails to read any property defined in the configuration repository.

I have

```
   @Value("${name}")
   private String name;
```

, and when starting up the service, I get a fairly lengthy stack trace stating that couldn't resolve `name` variable.

I have the following dependencies, so that list appears to be complete, unless I am not understanding something.

Thanks for taking a look.

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>




 objc[76575]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1080f44c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1081bc4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-11-24 10:27:25.205  INFO 76575 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@662ac478: startup date [Fri Nov 24 10:27:25 MST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-24 10:27:25.380  INFO 76575 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-11-24 10:27:25.410  INFO 76575 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5cd0890] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-11-24 10:27:25.704  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:9020
2017-11-24 10:27:25.800  WARN 76575 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: label not found
2017-11-24 10:27:25.801  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.mnrasul.springservice.Application    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-11-24 10:27:25.809  INFO 76575 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2a5b3fee: startup date [Fri Nov 24 10:27:25 MST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@662ac478
2017-11-24 10:27:26.089  WARN 76575 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2017-11-24 10:27:26.145  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=c18cae5c-1bd8-3d96-af3b-4871dd933a5f
2017-11-24 10:27:26.155  INFO 76575 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-11-24 10:27:26.222  INFO 76575 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5cd0890] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-11-24 10:27:26.416  INFO 76575 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9030 (http)
2017-11-24 10:27:26.423  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-11-24 10:27:26.424  INFO 76575 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-11-24 10:27:26.483  INFO 76575 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-11-24 10:27:26.484  INFO 76575 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 675 ms
2017-11-24 10:27:26.572  INFO 76575 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-11-24 10:27:26.574  INFO 76575 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-24 10:27:26.574  INFO 76575 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-24 10:27:26.574  INFO 76575 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-24 10:27:26.574  INFO 76575 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-24 10:27:26.831  INFO 76575 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2a5b3fee: startup date [Fri Nov 24 10:27:25 MST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@662ac478
2017-11-24 10:27:26.864  INFO 76575 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/name]}" onto java.lang.String com.mnrasul.springservice.MessageResource.getName()
2017-11-24 10:27:26.866  INFO 76575 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-11-24 10:27:26.867  INFO 76575 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-11-24 10:27:26.884  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-24 10:27:26.884  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-24 10:27:26.906  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-24 10:27:27.117  WARN 76575 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2017-11-24 10:27:27.117  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2017-11-24 10:27:27.119  WARN 76575 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2017-11-24 10:27:27.120  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2017-11-24 10:27:27.167  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-11-24 10:27:27.174  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-11-24 10:27:27.174  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-11-24 10:27:27.176  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-11-24 10:27:27.177  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2017-11-24 10:27:27.186  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2017-11-24 10:27:27.193  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=2a5b3fee,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2017-11-24 10:27:27.295  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-11-24 10:27:27.302  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2017-11-24 10:27:27.454  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-11-24 10:27:27.455  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-11-24 10:27:27.533  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2017-11-24 10:27:27.533  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2017-11-24 10:27:27.726  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2017-11-24 10:27:27.740  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2017-11-24 10:27:27.740  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2017-11-24 10:27:27.740  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2017-11-24 10:27:27.740  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2017-11-24 10:27:27.740  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2017-11-24 10:27:27.740  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2017-11-24 10:27:27.740  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-11-24 10:27:27.822  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2017-11-24 10:27:27.824  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2017-11-24 10:27:27.825  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2017-11-24 10:27:27.827  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1511544447827 with initial instances count: 6
2017-11-24 10:27:27.840  INFO 76575 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Registering application message with eureka with status UP
2017-11-24 10:27:27.840  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1511544447840, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2017-11-24 10:27:27.841  INFO 76575 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MESSAGE/192.168.2.9:message:9030: registering service...
2017-11-24 10:27:27.844  WARN 76575 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.messageResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in value "${name}"
2017-11-24 10:27:27.846  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-11-24 10:27:27.846  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2017-11-24 10:27:27.846  INFO 76575 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2017-11-24 10:27:27.848  WARN 76575 --- [           main] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2017-11-24 10:27:27.848  INFO 76575 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-11-24 10:27:27.858  INFO 76575 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-24 10:27:27.863  INFO 76575 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MESSAGE/192.168.2.9:message:9030 - registration status: 204
2017-11-24 10:27:27.868 ERROR 76575 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.messageResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in value "${name}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:359) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:176) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.start(RefreshScope.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:256) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:177) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.mnrasul.springservice.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in value "${name}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:831) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please' add there full stacktrace from your startup

Comment: @ArturCzopek I've attached the complete trace. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: add your `application.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have reviewed your code and find some  project errors, you want the name value from git. please refer to [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://github.com/forezp/SpringCloudLearning/tree/master/chapter6)

Comment: thanks a bunch. I was missing the `EnableConfigServer` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider here:

1. The name of your configuration file should be exactly the same as your spring.application.name. If the name is different, it will not work.
2. If you have spring profiles setup then you have to run your application using argument as "-Dspring.profiles.active=" eg Int or dev or test. Your property files should also be something like: Spring-service-int.yml or test.yml etc
   Note: In your startup logs I can see that you are booting on default so just check your profile.

Comment: Thanks. These concerns don't apply to this specific problem. default is intentional, as is looking up in `master` branch. My problem was, I had forgotten the `EnableConfigServer` annotation.

Comment: I met this issue and it requires to have te same spring.application.name. I didn't pay attention ! thanks